# Does gsutil cli tool support JSON output?

Tags: bash, gsutil

gsutil produces stdout output in it's custom key-value format which is quite inconvenient to parse. Is it possible to make gsutil generate JSON instead e.g. for this command:

```
gsutil ls -L gs://bucket-name/relative/path
```

Comment: The Output is in yaml format which is perfectly equivalent on how easy of hard is to parse.

Comment: @JoséSoní could you please provide a link where it says that the output is in yaml? I couldn't find it anywhere in the docs. And besides, in many languages JSON parser is a built-in library and for YAML you have to add a third-party dependency.

Comment: FWIW I opened a [feature request](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/1099) in the gsutil repo.

Answer (score 1):

The output will be in something that is closer to be yaml format. as mentioned in the code on the [official GitHub repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/master/gslib/commands/ls.py) and as part of `gsutil` the output format cannot be modified.

the output will be something like:

```
 gs://bucket/ :
            Storage class:                STANDARD
            Location constraint:          US
            Versioning enabled:           False
            Logging configuration:        None
            Website configuration:        None
            CORS configuration:           None
            Lifecycle configuration:      None
            Requester Pays enabled:       True
            Labels:                       None
            Default KMS key:              None
            Time created:                 Thu, 14 Jan 2016 19:25:17 GMT
            Time updated:                 Thu, 08 Jun 2017 21:17:59 GMT
            Metageneration:               1
            Bucket Policy Only enabled:   False
            ACL:
              [
                {
                  "entity": "project-owners-867489160491",
                  "projectTeam": {
                    "projectNumber": "867489160491",
                    "team": "owners"
                  },
                  "role": "OWNER"
                }
              ]
            Default ACL:
              [
                {
                  "entity": "project-owners-867489160491",
                  "projectTeam": {
                    "projectNumber": "867489160491",
                    "team": "owners"
                  },
                  "role": "OWNER"
                }
              ]
```

To get this as JSON i found this [go repository](https://github.com/fedir/json_encode) that can work for encode the output as a JSON

```
git clone https://github.com/fedir/json_encode.git
cd json_encode
go build

gsutil ls -L gs://bucket-name  | ./json_encode
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though replacing tabs with spaces is sufficient for pyyaml library to parse the output:

```
import re, subprocess, yaml

output = subprocess.check_output('gsutil ls -Lb gs://some-bucket-name'.split()).decode('utf-8')
bucket = yaml.safe_load(re.sub('\t', ' ', output))
```